# Please explain how to solve this error

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

```
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.1.0/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz
--2017-08-16 23:52:17--  http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.1.0/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin.tar.gz
Resolving www-us.apache.org (www-us.apache.org)... 140.211.11.105
Connecting to www-us.apache.org (www-us.apache.org)|140.211.11.105|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-08-16 23:52:32 ERROR 404: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's no 2.1.0 version of that program but there's 2.1.1.

Try to use this:

```
http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.1.1/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin.tar.gz
```

Comment: It is at www-us too: http://www-us.apache.org/dist/hive/hive-2.1.1/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin.tar.gz

Comment: but does it matter, both do the same?